# Performance of executing late bound method call vs. switch/case method selection

Tags: .net, reflection, ssis, etl, late-binding

While I've tagged this question with SSIS, it is not necessarily core to my question; So please keep reading if you're familiar with .NET reflection and code performance issues generally as you may be able to help!

But in particular, the fact that the associated code will be executed many times (ie against a data source on a per-row basis) is key.

I'm updating a pre-existing custom data flow control.

For each column in a row, the code must execute a specific method on the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer` instance (row), depending on the (column) SSIS data type.

For example,

```
public override void ProcessInput(int inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
{
    ...
    while (!buffer.EndOfRowset && buffer.NextRow())
    {
         ...
         someStringAtColumn1 = buffer.GetString(1);
         someIntAtColumn2 = buffer.GetInt16(2);
         someBoolAtColumn3 = buffer.GetBoolean(3);  

         //  And so on, for up to ~25 different types....
     }
     ...
}
```

But, the control needs to be dynamic, and hence we don't know at design-time, which type each column will be at run-time.

To that end, the pattern published at [SSIS Junkie
SSIS: Generic method for populating a pipeline buffer column](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/09/06/SSIS_3A00_-Generic-method-for-populating-a-pipeline-buffer-column.aspx) has been used (and works).  In summary, this uses a `SWITCH (buffer.GetColumnInfo(columnIndex).DataType)` to decide which of the ~25 methods to call against `buffer`.

**So, my questions:**

1. Is repeating this `SWITCH` statement for each column (number varies for each table, but let's say average of 10 columns) for every row (potentially millions), likely to cause a significant performance impact (in terms of processing time)?
2. Would it be better to late-bind to the the correct method for each column, on a per-table basis (ie *before* row-by-row processing starts), and then executing that column-specific late-bound method against each column (during the row-by-row processing)?

The approach I was thinking of would be something like:

```
// Set up per-column late-bound methods, once, prior to processing the rows
  System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] lateBoundMethods;

  //Psuedo code here for brevity...
  foreach column in tableDefinition {
      lateBoundMethods[i++] = getColumnSpecificGetValueMethod(column.DataType);
  }
  //End of psuedo code


private System.Reflection.MethodInfo getColumnSpecificGetValueMethod(DataType dataType)
{
    string methodName = "";

    switch (dataType)
    {
        case DataType.DT_BOOL:
            methodName = "GetBoolean";
            break;
        case DataType.DT_BYTES:
            methodName = "GetBytes";
            break;
        case DataType.DT_CY:
            methodName = "GetDecimal";
            break;

            ...

        case DataType.DT_WSTR:
            methodName = "GetString";
            break;
        default:
            return null; //TODO: Throw an exception?
    }

    System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(PipelineBuffer).GetMethod(
        methodName,
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.ExactBinding |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

    return methodInfo;
}

private object getValueFromBuffer(PipelineBuffer buffer, int columnIndex)
{
    if (buffer.IsNull(columnIndex))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return lateBoundMethods[columnIndex].Invoke(buffer, new object[] { columnIndex});
}
```

And then, during row processing, for each column I'd simply need to call

`Object columnValue = getValueFromBuffer(buffer, columnIndex);`.

So I guess question 2 comes down to "**Is executing a `.Invoke` against an *already*-bound `MethodInfo` going to be faster than executing the big switch/case?**".

**EDIT:** I appreciate that reflection is generally considered slow. But as per the bold question above, I'm not clear which *parts* of reflection are slow. I'm happy to wear poor performance during the pre-execution setup phase, so long as calling the late-bound methods is quicker than *choosing which ones* to call while processing rows. So, for any answer stating this will be slow, can you please clarify that you believe it is the invocation of a late-bound method that will be slow, vs. the task of identifying which method to bind.

I realise that no answer will be as definitive as running some tests... but I was looking for some (reasonably) authoritative indications up front and before investing significant effort, as deploying an ETL into our TEST environment for performance testing is non-trivial.

Also, I'm open to suggestions about other better ways to do this.

Your time and input appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using reflection for each row, which would be terribly slow. I'd suggest you use dictionary instead of switch statement and cache the reflected method (e.g. reflect only once per method = ~25 times + N dictionary lookups instead of N times reflection). That would improve performance considerably.

The ultimate answer would of course be writing a quick prototype and running a profiler, as you suggest.

Comment: I've suggested using .GetMethod() _once_ per column, before processing rows. And using .Invoke() once per column per row. Are you saying that .Invoke() is slow, even though the method to invoke was already reflected prior?

Comment: In fact, on re-reading this, you're basically suggesting the exact pattern I've proposed, except that you're using a dictionary rather than my array. I've updated my code comments to clarify that I am using GetMethod prior to processing rows.

Comment: Indeed, I seem to have missed that. Thanks for re-checking!

Comment: :-) are you able to clarify which (or both) of .GetMethod() and .Invoke() perform poorly?